# Trying to get property 'user_name' of non-object: trting to get data of a single row in single page

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, eloquent, controller

here is my controller page

```
public function getsinglepost($slug)
          {  
                $post = User::where('slug', $slug)->get();
                $post_1 = DB::select('select * from user_post');
                $name = request()->input('user_name');
                $email = request()->input('user_email');
                $question = request()->input('user_question');
                 return view('single')
                               ->with('user_name',$post_1->user_name)
                               ->with('user_email',$post_1->user_email)
                               ->with('user_question',$post_1->user_question)
                               ->with(['post_1'=>$post_1])  
  }
```

here is my migration

```
*/
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('user_name',100);
            $table->string('user_email',100);
            $table->string('user_question',900);
            $table->string('slug',900);
            $table->timestamp('created_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_post');
    }
}
```

here I am trying to get data of a single row in different pages made my slug
please do make any additions freely

Comment: what are you trying to do with this line `$post_1 = DB::select('select * from user_post');` ?

Comment: DB::select returns array, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you use the $request object and you pass only $slug in your function.

Your code should be like this:

```
public function getsinglepost(Request $request, $slug)
{
    // Your code
}
```

I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your query is wrong. and i think your needs is to get User Data based on slug column on user_post table

Maybe this will work:

```
public function getsinglepost($slug)
{  
      $post = DB::table('user_post')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
      return view('single', ['post' => $post]);
      // or like this
      return view('single', compact('post'));
}
```

Then on your view:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>User name</td>
    <td>{{ $post->user_name }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>{{ $post->user_email }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td>{{ $post->user_question }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This worked fine for me... Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem, can you mark this as answered if this was helpful to you?